# Wrting a string to csv

Tags: python

I append a few things and in the end i have a list that looks like this

```
listed = ['53.02 12.36 120 33.6', 0.32 ,65 , '52 26.3 66 39.12' ,0.65 , 96]
```

Now i run this in a loop and at every iteration of the loop i get this list and i want to append this list to a csv with each line looking like this

```
53.02 12.36 120 33.6 0.32 65 52 26.3 66 39.12 0.65 96
```

i tried doing

```
        listed = ' '.join(str(ele) for ele in listed)
```

but that gives a space for every number somewhat looking like this

```
5,3,.,0,2, ,1,2,.,3,6, ,0,.,2
```

Any ideas on how i may do this

Part of the code looks like this

```
f = open('Testing.csv', 'a')
writer = csv.writer(f, delimiter = '\t')
for index in range(len(dataset_train)):

        for box, score, label in zip(image_boxes, image_scores, image_labels):
            box = str(box).lstrip('[').rstrip(']')
            listed.append(box)
            listed.append(score)
            listed.append(label)
        listed = ' '.join(str(ele) for ele in listed)
        listed = list(listed)
        writer.writerow(listed)
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
import csv
from itertools import chain

listed = ['53.02 12.36 120 33.6', 0.32 ,65 , '52 26.3 66 39.12' ,0.65 , 96]
listed = list(chain.from_iterable([str(i).split() for i in listed]))   #Flatten list

with open(filename, "w") as infile:
    writer = csv.writer(infile, delimiter = '\t')
    writer.writerow(listed)        #Write row
```

**Output:**

```
53.02   12.36   120 33.6    0.32    65  52  26.3    66  39.12   0.65    96
```

Answer (score 1):

You're going a bit too deep - the `.join()` method works on *any* iterable object, including a String - which is what you're giving it. What you want is

```
listed = ' '.join( [str(ele) for ele in listed] )
```

See the inner square brackets, there, that bind `[str(ele) for ele in listed]` into a single iterable object, which will then be joined.